# Unity3d,integrate correctly with a json api?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm pretty new to c# and unity i'm trying to create a class able to talk with an external server via json API.

It was fine until I saw the code and I was repeating the same pieces over and over (basically each method of the API had its Ienumerator function with the JSON.Parse part.

So I started thinking that it would have been better to create a single function Get_Json and make it able to return the API request in form of object. I hit a wall and I literally have no idea how go ahead, I would really appreciate some help on how to make this correct:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using SimpleJSON;


public class Site : MonoBehaviour {

    /*
        base url http://example.com/
        * GET a Room:    /ajax/API/?method=Get&hashtag=HASHTAG
        * Create a Room: /ajax/API/?method=Create&hashtag=HASHTAG&token=TOKEN (optional)
        * Delete a Room: /ajax/API/?method=Delete&hashtag=HASHTAG&token=TOKEN
        * List Rooms:    /ajax/API/?method=List_rooms
        * List Hashtags: /ajax/API/?method=List_hashtags

    */

    private string base_url = "http://example.com/ajax/API/?method=";
    private string q = "";

    IEnumerator Get_Json(string q){

        var url = base_url+q;
        WWW www = new WWW(url);
        yield return www;

        Debug.Log(www.text);

        if (www.error == null){

            var Resource = JSON.Parse(www.text);

            if(int.Parse(Resource["Code"]) == 200){
                Debug.Log("All right");
            }
            else{
                Debug.Log(Resource["Code"]);
            }

        }
        else{
            Debug.Log("Failed an http request:\n"+url+"\n"+www.error);
        }

        yield return null;

    }

     // Use this for initialization
     void Start () {
        StartCoroutine(Get_Json("List_rooms"));
     }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

Comment: Slightly offtopic: why are you using coroutines here? Since your coroutine only ever yields `null` you may as well just use a regular method.  Also, using `q` as both a field and the parameter name is confusing to read - your code would make more sense if you renamed one of the two. More on-topic: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. Is it that you want your method to return `Resource`? What type are you expecting `Resource` to be?

Comment: Hi, while reading the documentation I understood that coroutines are the correct type of functions when dealing with http requests,
due to the asynchronous nature of the http protocol.
I agree on q, I'll fix that.
Basically I'm trying to create a method that is invoked wiht a parameter "List_rooms" and returns the available rooms.
After that I'll use the same function to get a room details, ie: "Get_Room" "Room1", "Token"
Before trying to implement a single method I had several little functions doing this but I didn't like how the code was.
cheers

Comment: What "wall" have you hit?  You appear to have a perfectly valid www parser that responds to your queries.  If the problem is how to call the queries in order you could always put them in a queue and then add a nested coroutine that recalls your `Get_Json` until the queue is empty.

Comment: Yes, That's how I finally did it. I thought for some reasons that nesting coroutines was bad, apparently it works really fine.